# What is wrong with this latex code?

Tags: tables, pdftex, miktex, code, resume

please help me, I am trying to nest tabular.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{6.0cm}|p{8.5cm}|p{1.8cm}|}
\hline
\centering{\textbf{Year}} & \centering{\textbf{Degree/Certificate}} & \centering{\textbf{Institute}} & \textbf{CPI/$\%$}\\
\hline
\centering{2017} - Present & \begin{tabular}{c}\hline \centering{B.Tech : BSBE} \\ \hline \centering{M.Sc : MTH}\\ \end{tabular}  & \centering{Indian Institute of Technology, Kanpur} & 9.8/10\\
\hline
\centering{2017} & \centering{CBSE(\Romannum{12})} & \centering{Aklank Public School, Kota} & 91.2$\%$\\
\hline
\centering{2015} & \centering{ICSE(\Romannum{10})} & \centering{Saint Francis School, Jasidih} & 97$\%$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Can you post your expectation as image? Hence, not sure why you are using `\centering` inside may column. Also post your `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: How or where is `\Romannum` defined?

Comment: Unrelated: `\centering` does not take arguments. Also what is `\Romannum` suppose to do and where does it come from?

Comment: @SHASHWATSANJEEV did the answer help you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with some simplifications, using the `w` columntype defined by recent versions of `array` and the `makecell` package. Note that column widths are very large for the text in cells, and I had to `load` geometry with option `a3paper`. You should see if the given dimensions are really necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, hhline, multirow}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{|w{c}{2.5cm}|w{c}{6.0cm}|w{c}{8.5cm}|p{1.8cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Year} & \textbf{Degree/Certificate} & \textbf{Institute} & \textbf{CPI/\%}\\
\hline
2017 -- Present & \makecell{ B.Tech : BSBE \\\hline\noalign{\vspace{2pt}} M.Sc : MTH} & Indian Institute of Technology, Kanpur & 9.8/10\\
\hline
2017 & CBSE(\Romannum{12}) & Aklank Public School, Kota & 91.2\,\%\\
\hline
2015 & ICSE(\Romannum{10}) & Saint Francis School, Jasidih & 97\,\%\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

removed romanum since undefined --see if it meets your requirement

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5in}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2in}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1in}|}
    \hline
    Year & 
    Degree/Certificate & 
    Institute & 
    CPI/$\%$\\
    \hline
    2017 - Present & 
    B.Tech    & 
    Indian Institute of Technology, Kanpur & 
    9.8/10\\
    
    &BSBE M.Sc : MTH&&\\\hline
    2017 & 
    CBSE({12}) & 
    Aklank Public School, Kota & 
    91.2$\%$\\
    \hline
    2015 & 
    ICSE({10}) & 
    Saint Francis School, Jasidih & 
    97$\%$\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```